# Dig returns Refused Status on norecurse?

Tags: dig

I've looked up two questions here at serverfault, but my question's a little different in specificity - when running the dig command with the +norecurs option (I'm trying to experiment with cache here - by running it once with +norecurs and another time without), I get the REFUSED stats as shown below. Would appreciate an explanation of why this happens instead of returning with a NOERROR status normally. Thanks!

```
dig www.mangabb.me +norecurs


; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> www.mangabb.me +norecurs
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: REFUSED, id: 20157
;; flags: qr ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.mangabb.me.            IN  A

;; Query time: 2 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.1#53(192.168.1.1)
;; WHEN: Wed Apr  2 21:39:37 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 32
```

**UPDATE: Okay, I tried specifying a server like this:

`dig @202.120.224.26 www.mangabb.me +norecurs` and it worked!

Why does the root server . not work?

Comment: dig without an `@<nameserver>` option will default to your local nameservers as configured in `/etc/resolv.conf`. 192.168.1.1 is the server you need to blame, not the root servers.

Comment: If 192.168.1.1 is running Bind 9, have a look at the option `allow-query-cache{}`

Comment: Ahh...I see what you mean - still new to this terminology. Will keep that in mind for future reference. Thanks!

Comment: The Bind option I mentioned will return an error if it is set to not allow cache queries, though if it does allow recursion, that means it's no longer a caching DNS server (which would be odd). Here's a bit more info: http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/queries.html#allow-query-cache